Need the "how" steps to ask legitimate non-judgemental regarding issues needing resolution to inspire peaceful negotiation
Children are expected to ask questions. Jewish people are supposed to answer those who ask regardless of their knowledge/upbringing - i.e., the four sons represented in the Haggadah. In order to motivate children to ask questions, they have to be validated by the parent/teacher/example of a Jewish person that "no question is a bad question" (even though children may have judgemental viewpoints many times when asking those questions).
What are the specific "rules" to teach children about parameters of how to ask a question so that the parents can teach mutual respect/rules in simple ways children can understand (teaching how to avoid conflict)?
How do these rules apply to people who who ask questions that are not "allowed" to be taught certain subjects?  I.e., non-Jews, women, others?
It would be ideal if the source for this mitzvah/step process stems from a reliable source relating to something specific (Torah maisa) that can become the root of those rules: deiraisa prohibition(s) and/or leniency(ies).  Ideally disscussesing the matter in depth, hopefully rooted in behaviors/events specifically related to the Avos. Teaching this to children w/ the intention to inspire knowledge of how to initiate peaceful resolutions relating to higher conflict and or disputed issues (universal - inside or outside of the communtiy).
